# trouble accessing usr/src/linux in kernel customization

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

im trying to customize the kernel in virtualbox. When running usr/src/linux I am getting the error "/usr/src/linux no such file or directory exists"

below are the steps i followed to customize the kernel, im on step 10 trying to compile the kernel from usr/scr/linux

1. Obtain kernel source code rpm file from a CentOS Update mirror site:

Logon as "root" and make sure your current working directory is /root. If it is not, cd /root.

Then type one the following commands at the shell prompt (any of these kernel versions will do):

wget http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-3.10.0-693.1.1.el7.src.rpm

Note: if the above kernel source code is no longer available from the mirror site, please download the latest distribution listed on that site.

2. yum install rpm-build
3. yum install redhat-rpm-config
4. yum install xmlto asciidoc hmaccalc python-devel newt-devel
5. yum install perl-ExtUtils-Embed pesign elfutils-devel zlib-devel binutils-devel
6. yum install audit-libs-devel java-devel numactl-devel pciutils-devel ncurses-devel
7. Unpackage the kernel source. Execute the following command from the directory that contains the kernel source rpm package you downloaded in step 1 above (likely /root)

rpm -Uvh kernel-3.10.*.src.rpm

If you see a series of warning messages like the following, just disregard them:

warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root

warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root

8. Change directory (cd) to /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/  (verify this directory exists), and issue the following command:

rpmbuild -bp --target=x86_64 kernel.spec

Generic: rpmbuild -bp --target=$(uname -m) kernel.spec

9. Kernel tree will be located in /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/ (verify that this directory exists). Link to it from /usr/src with the following command:

   ln -s /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-3.10.0-693.1.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-693.1.1.el7.x86_64 /usr/src/linux

NOTE: verify path /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-3.10.0-693.1.1.el7/linux-3.10.0-693.1.1.el7.x86_64 exists and adjust accordingly to match the kernel source version that you have installed.

10. Compile new kernel and its modules (run the following make commands from /usr/src/linux):

make bzImage

make modules

make

im on step 10 trying to run from usr/src/linux but its saying the file or directory doesnt exist

however when i look in usr/src by typing ls usr/src it outputs 
"debug kernels linux linux-3.10.0-693.1.1.el7.x86_64"

doesnt that mean its there? what should i do

Comment: It's a symlink. Does the thing it points to exist? Run `ls -l /usr/src` to see where it points to.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: yikes:  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @immibis i ran that the output is "total 0"